# Define value type of Typescript Mapped Type without using Record<> (which allows for any key to be used)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a Typescript model for Firestore to allow for more type-safe reads and writes. Here was my first attempt:

```
type PossibleDocValues = number | string | boolean | PossibleDocValues[] | { [key: string]: PossibleDocValues };
type Doc = Record<string, PossibleDocValues | Collection>
type Collection = { [key: string]: Doc }

type ExcludeKeysWithTypeOf<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? never : K 
}[keyof T]

type Without<T, V> = Pick<T, ExcludeKeysWithTypeOf<T, V>>;

//PureDoc should return a Doc with all Collection properties stripped
type PureDoc<T extends Doc> = Without<T, Collection>

//TEST STARTS HERE
interface testDoc extends Doc{
  foo: string,
  bar: string[],
  col: testCollection
}

interface testDoc2 extends Doc{
  foo1: string,
  bar1: string[],
}

interface testDoc3 extends Doc{
  foo2: string,
  bar2: string[],
}

interface testCollection extends Collection {
  [key: string]: testDoc2 
  test: testDoc3 //Also cant do overrides like this
}

const test: PureDoc<testDoc> = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: [],
  col: {}, //Doesn't error (should error because of PureDoc)
  doesntexist: "hi" //Doesn't error though (should since its not part of testDoc)
}
```

This works *mostly* fine, but during testing I noticed two things:

1. Because of my use of `Record<>` and `{ [key: string]: Doc }`, extending from Doc makes it impossible for TS to notify me of properties that are not actually part of the doc being implemented (see `const test: PureDoc<testDoc>` at the bottom)
2. I can't have a collection with one main doc type and overrides for another doc type at specific keys (see `interface testCollection extends Collection`) This is much less of a problem, though.

I can't use this unless problem 1 is solved. So, I'm wondering, is there a way for me to define the allowed types for the values of a mapped type and all its inheritors (which will have finite keys) without using Record<> or {[key: string]: T}, which automatically permits all keys?

PS: I tied another attempt using Generics and making a type that trips values from a map that don't fit the permitted types, but things get very messy. [Have a look here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIBE4GMBqAhugK4QJQC8UAdiQLaoQBOUAPlAsM8jQObsoqOHEyEag+EjSYcBYmQQBtALqCA3lCUBrCCABcnbrz4rDUlBmx4ipclAC+AbgBQL0JChyAPABUAfFRQ6i5QWgDSULxQuiBwAGZQvmqGvkrhahAAHsAQNAAmFBYy1vJ2FAD8SekptBAAbiwuDm4A9K0A8o3M6CBQ+cjx8ci4JOjAUMBwUADuPLm0cDMANFAAklBgzHCohBh9A-k0AOQTc8gLwAAWyBS4cMzMELjAve7g0ADCopgvyHA0PyBaghMLpKISWIJJK1NIZKDZXIFCg+AJQKpw2o0BpNFrvTwAUSyuFI+Qg4T0CAA6hcrr4Ph14n5VvhgcFQhEITE9NDkqkagicnlClB8Oi6t0oIZIs0dDzEsk3B5oDTrnASMBmaK2TARtotUSSSQyRSQNTafTIIytaz-K58dAYCQnqi2aqrurNb5Vt90L9gP9AeIQP5-G4XO1fASAMq+KCxgCCACVfNGoAAJAlJgkOybkYByII+UFQeIiQxcHj8ZYc3bMCvGfiqGthe7oQy5Li+-2B5ph3Odgt4ABMRbw3hLZbgAEYG1W+C2hIRmLOjPPmxy26usIQFu0cOQThMnvlS+hCAuhBqoncAd1cqeplBCBKWFAABQzG64K5QeiEXQKAQPJgNWVBr1uTgSGEMAA3-dAAEo+yVD48y4OQAGYx1wCcOXqBQIEMOhGBYGsHH7ZU0OAbtngDAEghov4AVwsE4GuFgEDnEwzCouRhw5AFSg7fNMNWdoE3QBBplwcQJnyaY4G6HgyQodBkF0SYbgQZCXHuGguCo8xnVKbxBzkNlJ3LKAACIp2sxc60MJRrMHayVDE1oADEHk4OB6GgStxD4aAnkIKSJGuSD5MPU5ZgebQKmaIA).

Comment: could you please provide more test exmaples and clarify why you expect an error